# Out of source build with jam?

Tags: build, jam

Is it possible to do an out-of-source build using Jam? If yes, how?

(I've been sifting through the manual, but it makes no mention of this as far as I can see.)

**Note:** I am using the "standard" Jam v2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might depend on the version of jam you are using. Speaking for the standard jam (i.e. not the Boost or FreeType forks): There is no official way, but you might get away with:

```
jam -sJAMFILE=path/to/Jamfile ...
```

For more complex build systems that also have a configure stage, I'd recommend to simply generate a minimal Jamfile in those output directory/directories from which you intend to invoke jam.

Comment: To clarify what I mean by "get away with": `JAMFILE` is supposed to contain the name, not the path, of your Jamfiles (e.g. if you want/need to use another naming convention), but where the (standard 2.5) Jambase uses the variable, it replaces the path anyway. So despite the hacky use of `JAMFILE`, there shouldn't be any problems with the standard rules at least.

Comment: ...turns out the Jamfile of the project I'm looking at chokes at this use of `jam`, as it does some configuring / recursive globbing. Bugger. Thanks anyway!